# How to setup logrotate properly for multiple systemd services, which sends their stdout, stderr to rsyslog

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, logrotate

Suppose I have many systemd service units on `ubuntu 16.04` which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do something script
After=default.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/some-script-x.sh
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=some-script

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Also I have configured rsyslog like this:

```
if $programname == 'some-script-x' then /var/log/some-script-x.log
```

Done. Service logs writes to their logs.

I want to rotate `/var/log/some-script-x.log` like default log files, like syslog. I have an prototype of config:

```
/var/log/some-script-x.log
{
        rotate 30
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

But the system already has a file `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` that contains the following `invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null`.

In this configuration case there is multiple rotate calls to syslog server . It worries me. How to tell rsyslog that I want to rotate only specific service log. Or how to setup rotation properly, without extra calls?